# how can i get bank account number from source in stripe API?

Tags: stripe-payments, plaid, stripe.js

I am using ACH payment for collecting money from customer as investment. I can add bank account using plaid and stripe. But how can i get bank account number from source in stripe API?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot. By design, Stripe's API will not return the full account number, only the last 4 digits (via the [`last4`](https://stripe.com/docs/api#customer_bank_account_object-last4) attribute).